# Can a website log our screen activities even without telling us?

Tags: logging, privacy, screen-capture, screensharing

Hangouts can to share entire screen of user. Can a site that if opened in a tab starts sharing our screen to spy. if it is possible then I will create a webpage and then send the link to my friend and log his screen. is it possible?

If this is possible then there is huge threat to privacy. Maybe some website `xyz.com` I have opened and kept open in one tab might have started logging all my activities by sharing my screen with spy.

If hangouts can do that without permissions then it must be an easy way of hacking as someone can easily log my screen and look into my password dialog box while I am entering the passwords

Answer (score 0):

This is off-topic for SO.

Hangouts *can't* do that without permission, however, there is always scope for bugs, especially in browser plugins - FWIW for me, Hangouts is buggy and has never worked properly.

You're far more likely to be attacked invisibly by a keylogger, cryptominer, or other simpler, less-obvious attack, such as in the recent Magecart / British Airways hack. Take a look at [this course](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/defending-javascript-keylogger-attacks-pci) for how to defend against that kind of thing.